# Почему сайт пишет, что я бот?

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, requests, beautiful-soup

Посылаю POST запрос на сайт, а сайт меня фильтрует.

Все данные для запроса у меня есть (генератор), headers тоже все поменял (как в браузере), да вот только в браузере все проходит, а в responce в приложении пишет что я бот.

Думаю, что там есть JS скрипт который отрабатывает и делает мол bot = false, да вот requests не грузит JS.

Вот сам сайт https://tronfaucet.top

Comment: но ведь так и есть ;) много запросов делаете? бан по ip не может быть причиной?

Comment: попробуйте поставить браузерный user-agent в заголовки вашего запроса

Comment: Я делаю 1 запрос только, потом кидаю запрос с браузера, дабы проверить вдруг забанили; но браузер возвращает все правильно, а программа - нет( user-agent совпадает с браузерным, и не только user-agent; accept и д.р параметры

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей. [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Jack_oS Код то работает, да сайт не пропускает: 
Ошибка на сайте(сохранил респонсе в html): https://prnt.sc/13ikl1u 
headers: https://prnt.sc/13iksjt 
responce1 - get запрос
responce - post запрос

Answer (score 3):

Минут десять уже работает:

```
import requests
from time import sleep
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://tronfaucet.top/'
headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.212 Safari/537.36'}

def parser():
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    tables = soup.find_all('table')
    rows = tables[-1].find_all('tr')[1:]

    for row in rows:
        tds = row.find_all('td')

        address = tds[0].text
        amount = tds[1].text
        when = tds[2].text
        type_amount = tds[3].text

        print(f'{address:8} {amount:15} {when:7} {type_amount}')

while True:
    parser()
    print('---------------------------------------------')
    sleep(3)
```

выводит:

```
TKp...X  0.00342216 TRX  11s ago claim
TYR...s  0.00342216 TRX  15s ago claim
TPq...V  0.00342216 TRX  59s ago claim
THm...Z  0.00342216 TRX  1m ago  claim
TJr...N  0.00027378 TRX  2m ago  ref. com.
0xe...c  0.00068443 TRX  2m ago  claim
TVt...A  0.00068443 TRX  2m ago  claim
TP3...o  0.00068443 TRX  2m ago  claim
TJ9...R  0.00342216 TRX  3m ago  claim
TBq...A  0.00068443 TRX  3m ago  claim
TWr...u  0.00136886 TRX  3m ago  claim
---------------------------------------------

...

TAb...P  0.00068443 TRX  8s ago  claim
TKp...X  0.00342216 TRX  19s ago claim
TYR...s  0.00342216 TRX  23s ago claim
TPq...V  0.00342216 TRX  1m ago  claim
THm...Z  0.00342216 TRX  1m ago  claim
TJr...N  0.00027378 TRX  2m ago  ref. com.
0xe...c  0.00068443 TRX  2m ago  claim
TVt...A  0.00068443 TRX  2m ago  claim
TP3...o  0.00068443 TRX  3m ago  claim
TJ9...R  0.00342216 TRX  3m ago  claim
TBq...A  0.00068443 TRX  3m ago  claim
---------------------------------------------
```

Не принимает за бота ;)

Comment: эта инфа и мне доступна мне post запрос нужен, когда кошелек отправляется
это не то выводится, мне нужно отправить запрос с кошельком и параметром challenge и получить монеты на кошелек) запрос я отправляю верный вместе с challenge но вот он пишет мол я бот и поэтому не отправляет, у мене есть js файл с решением challenge, можете попробовать)

Comment: Your Tron address must be linked to FaucetPay.
Up to 15 claims per day allowed.
You must wait 10 minutes between claims.
Please don't cheat (do not use vpn, bots etc.).

вы это читали?

Comment: поконкретнее? вы про последнюю строку? если да то это просьба администрации, так то мы все пользователи те же запросы отправляем) а если про кошелек то вот TG771cpnVhPYgsa7Xjcmreqm2wtzM2ApiC
если про задержку то да я её учитывал

Comment: вы challenge меняете? а куки?

Comment: @maksimx можно вопрос не по коду? смотрю на последние транзакции на этой странице и вижу максимум - 0.00409641... при нынешней стоимости через год вам накапает... $1,65! оно того стОит? ;)

Comment: да стоит того, куки меняю сессия другая же, но вроде брал с браузера все равно не пускает

Comment: @maksimx нужно понять, как формируется  value для challenge... там есть код  <div style="padding:5px 0px;"><form 
            var doger = function(d)   ...многабукафф...   /script>
            <p><label>Your Tron address: <br><input type=text name=a></label> <input type=submit value="Get Free TRX!"></p>
        </form></div>method=post>
            <input type=hidden name=challenge id=challenge value="">
            <script>   т.е. изначально value - пустой, его генерирует скрипт при каждой перезагрузке страницы

Comment: я знаю как он генерируется - я его генерирую, сайт не пропускает